# Xtext: DSL Wizard - Create a Java project, but not as a plug-in

Tags: eclipse, plugins, wizard, xtext, projects

I have this in my work flow

```
    fragment = ui.projectWizard.SimpleProjectWizardFragment2 {
        generate = true
    }
```

Which enables a DSL wizard, but the projects that are created with the wizard are plug-in projects.

If I add the following flag

```
pluginProject = false
```

The projects are not plug-in (which is good) but I can't add Java classes.

How can I make the wizard to create a project that supports both .dsl files and .java files without making it a plug-in project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simply customizing the stuff created by the workflow ???

```
class MyDslProjectCreatorCustom extends MyDslProjectCreator {

    override protected getBuilders() {
        #[XtextProjectHelper.BUILDER_ID, "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"]
    }

    override protected getProjectNatures() {
        #[XtextProjectHelper.NATURE_ID, "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature"]
    }

}
```

and

```
@FinalFieldsConstructor
class MyDslUiModule extends AbstractMyDslUiModule {

    def Class<? extends ProjectFactory> bindProjectFactory() {
        JavaProjectFactory    
    }

    override bindIProjectCreator() {
        MyDslProjectCreatorCustom
    }

}
```